# Newsstand and network errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, newsstand-kit

Guys I'm working on the Newsstand stuff now. I'm trying to handle network errors.

What you see on the image below is my simple log ("Percentage: %i" is inside `connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:`).

My problem is depicted in the last 3 lines of code.

[image]

What I've done in this lines:

1. After that line I've switched on the airplane mode (simulated network error)
2. I've received `connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:` with `totalBytesWritten` equal to `expectedTotalBytes`
3. I've received `connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL`.

After that:

Hooray, I've just finished downloading my .zip, I can unpack it, announce the status to my view and so on... :(

**My question is what's going on?**

I have implemented `connection:didFailWithError:` but it's not invoked.

I was trying to grab the `totalBytesWritten` in last invoked `didWriteData:` and compare it to real file size in `DidFinishDownloading:`

I have stripped all my project away just to make sure that its not related to my whole design.

I'm thinking about combination of `NSTimer` and `NKIssueContentStatusAvailable` to check the real download status.

**It's all hacky. Isn't it?**

Update:

- Reproduced on iOS 6 and 7 with XCode 5
- All NewsstandKit methods invoked on the main thread
- Same thing when simulating offline mode with Charles proxy (app in foreground)

Comment: I noticed this issue too, with iOS7. This is annoying because you cannot trust the downloaded data and you must test its integrity before any download. I think we should open a radar.

Comment: I was checking it on iOS 6 too - same thing

Comment: Yes, the problem can be reproduced on both ios6 and 7 when the SDK 7 + Xcode 5 is used. I don't remember this issue with the old SDK. I don't know how the new SDk can affect older iOS6 installations indeed.

Comment: Just for sanity check, did you try downloading the file from the URL using curl? Or can you try downloading it with a regular NSURLRequest?

Comment: Yes, downloading with NSURLConnection is ok. Simulating the offline results in `connection:didFailWithError:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue anymore when switching to Airplane, but still can reproduce the issue when throttling on Charles proxy.

I ended up with this solution (checking if `connection:didWriteData:...` is telling the truth in `connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:`):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes
{
    ...
    self.declaredSizeOfDownloadedFile = expectedTotalBytes;
}
```

And:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *) destinationURL
{
    NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:destinationURL.absoluteString error:nil];
    NSNumber* destinationFileSize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    if (destinationFileSize.intValue != self.declaredSizeOfDownloadedFile)
    {
        NSError* error = ...;
        [self connection:connection didFailWithError:error];

        self.declaredSizeOfDownloadedFile = 0;

        return;
    }

    ...
}
```